# Cannot read property 'target' of undefined - Ionic Angular

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

What im doing wrong to get this error?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-uploader',
  templateUrl: './uploader.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploader.page.scss'],
})
export class UploaderPage implements OnInit {

  imageURL: string
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  fileChanged(event) {
    const files = event.target.files
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('file', files[0])
    data.append('UPLOADCARE_STORE', '1')
    data.append('UPLOADCARE_PUB_KEY', 'my key')

    this.http.post('https://upload.uploadcare.com/base/', data).subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event)
      this.imageURL = event.json().file
    })
  }


}
```

But when i upload a photo i get this error and also i get error that json does not exist  on type 'Object'

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
>       at UploaderPage.fileChanged (uploader.page.ts:16)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (UploaderPage.ngfactory.js:26)
>       at Object.handleEvent (core.js:43993)
>       at Object.handleEvent (core.js:44774)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
>       at core.js:42925
>       at HTMLInputElement. (platform-browser.js:2668)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)

EDITED:
This is the HTML "caller"

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Upload Image</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div class="camera"> </div>
  <input type="file" (change)="fileChanged()"/>

  <img *ngIf="imageURL" src="https://ucarecdn.com/{{ imageURL}}/"/>
</ion-content>
```

**UPDATE**
The first part of the problem i got fixed by [alexortizl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11899771/alexortizl) (the accepted answer below).

The json part i fixed it from this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448660/argument-of-type-object-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string-ioni) where i just need to remove json.parse because the url was already in json format.

Comment: Perhaps the `event` is not being passed to the function correctly? can you share the caller?

Comment: @arif08 by caller what do you mean?

Comment: @MahirMersimoski  Can you show us the component HTML?

Comment: @alexortizl there u go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event` is undefined in `fileChanged` because it's not being passed when the event is raised. You need to pass the event payload in the HTML:

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChanged($event)"/>
```

This is angular syntax, here `$event` is the variable with the `Event` object raised by the `change` event.

Comment: thank you it makes sense but i have problem with the json thing " Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'."

Comment: In this case `event` refers to the POST response, it could be a good idea to rename it to something else to avoid confusion with the other `event` variable. If you need to parse that response to json you could try `this.imageURL = JSON.parse(event).file`

Comment: now i get error in the (event) saying Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: @MahirMersimoski what is shown in the console when you do `console.log(event)`?