# Argument of type ‘Object’ is not assignable to parameter of type ‘string’ - Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Trying to parse with JSON but i get this error:
Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-uploader',
  templateUrl: './uploader.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploader.page.scss'],
})
export class UploaderPage implements OnInit {

  imageURL: string
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  fileChanged(event) {
    const files = event.target.files
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('file', files[0])
    data.append('UPLOADCARE_STORE', '1')
    data.append('UPLOADCARE_PUB_KEY', '12d3f0b0b65cb448aa6b')

    this.http.post('https://upload.uploadcare.com/base/', data).subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event)
      this.imageURL = JSON.parse(event).file
    })
  }


}
```

In the line `this.imageURL = JSON.parse(event).file` under (event) i get that error. What could be the cause and how to fix it.

The HTML :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Upload Image</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div class="camera"> </div>
  <input type="file" (change)="fileChanged($event)"/>

  <img *ngIf="imageURL" src="https://ucarecdn.com/{{ imageURL}}/"/>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: What is the need of `JSON.parse()` here? Is `event` response a string in the format of a JSON?

Comment: @MichaelD i need a url of the upload in uploadcare so i can show the photo in my html code

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. It appears [the response](https://uploadcare.com/docs/api_reference/upload/request_based/) from the POST request is already in JSON format. You don't need the `JSON.parse()` here. Try the following

```js
this.http.post('https://upload.uploadcare.com/base/', data).subscribe(
  event => {
    this.imageURL = event.file;
  },
  error => { // handle error }
);
```

It is also good practice to make the actual HTTP request in a service and to handle the error in the subscription.

Comment: even tho it works i get the pic and i can show it in my HTML but i get the following: Property 'file' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: That might be a TS Lint error because it doesn't have any reference to the object returned by the API. You could overcome it by using `this.imageURL = event['file'];` instead.

Comment: really helpful thank you very much, it solved my problem